# Listbox Get SelectedItem in the ItemsPanel

Tags: wpf, listbox, stackpanel, itemspanel

I have a listbox with a custom stackpanel (just a class extended a stackpanel now but i am hoping to do some animation here) as its itemspanel. Now when the selection changes I thought of doing some nice animation between the last selected item and the current selected item.

Now my problem is how do I get hold of the selected item in the itemspanel?

This is how I am defining my itemspanel

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <l:CustomStackPanel SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=listbox}"  IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

I created a dependencyproperty in my custom stackpanel called SelectedItem

```
public UIElement SelectedItem
        {
            get { return (UIElement)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(UIElement), typeof(CustomStackPanel), new PropertyMetadata(null,selectionChanged));
```

And I thought I could simply bind the selectedItem in my listbox to the selecteditem in the stackpanel. But this approach is simply not working.

Another thought was to override previewmousedown on the stackpanel and find the corresponding item from the **Children** of the stackpanel. But again I am not sure how to find the item.

Comment: If you use binding then `SelectedItem` won't be of a `UIElement` type but bound list item type. `Selector.SelectedItem` is of `Object` type. Do you want `ListBoxItem`?

Comment: Yes I want the ListBoxItem. My intention was to 'Light Up' the items in between the current and previous selected items (Like creating a animated Path on selection Changed). Since the children of the stackpanel are of UIElement Collection, I thought the selected item would be of type UIElement?

Comment: Bound items are wrapped in `ListBoxItem` for display but `SelectedItem(s)` stay of bound list item type. You can get `ListBoxItem` from `SelectedItem` using [`ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I think this is pointing me in the right direction. Do you think I can achieve that animation effect using this approach? I need to get the index of last selected item and the index of the current selected item. And I need to animate all the items between these 2 items.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve what you want - light up items in between - in pure XAML but in code it's doable.

Comment: Yes I am trying to do it in the code. That is why I created CustomStackPanel so that I get access to all child elements. I just need to get the items in between the selected items now.

Answer (score 1):

Use RelativeSource in your binding

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
     <l:CustomStackPanel SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=x:Type ListBox}}"  IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical"/>
 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: Edit - Actually it is working as soon as I change my type from UIElement to my actual type (which is say ItemViewModel). But I need it as a UIElement from the Children collection of the stackpanel so that I can do some animation. :(

Comment: you can't get UIelement using binding.. as suggested by @dkozl you will have to use ItemContainerGenerator once you get the selecteditem as i suggested